# Find the Maclaurin series of the function and the raidus of convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$f(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{4+x^2}}$ Here is the original function given

$f(x) = \frac{x}{2\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{4}}}$ First I tried to simplify the term in the denominator by factoring out a 2

$\frac{1}{2}x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \Big(1+\frac{x^2}{4}\Big)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ Then I set the function up in the binomial form with a constant pulled out front where: $(1+x)^k = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \Big(\frac{k}{n}\Big) x^n = 1+kx+\frac{k(k-1)}{2!} x^2+...$ and $\vert x \vert \lt 1$. In the form that I have $\vert x \vert = \vert\frac{x^2}{4}\vert$

$ k= -\frac{1}{2}$ $x^n = \frac{x^2}{4}$

The series converges at 1 since $-1\lt k \leq 0$ 
The radius of convergence is $[0,2)$ because when $\vert x \vert = 0,1,2$ then $\vert x \vert \lt 1$

Is this done properly, or is this series best represented by another type of Maclaurin Series?

Answer (score 1):

You brought in the summation notation too soon!

However, you are not too far off:

$f(x) = x(4+x^2)^{-1/2} = x[4 (1 + \frac{x^2}{4})]^{-1/2} = \frac{1}{2} x(1 + \frac{x^2}{4})^{-1/2}$.

Now, recall the Binomial Theorem with exponent $-\frac{1}{2}$:

$$(1 + t)^{-1/2} = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{-1/2}{n} t^n,$$
where $\binom{-1/2}{n} = \frac{(-1/2)(-1/2 - 1) ... (-1/2 + n - 1)}{n!}$.

This series converges when $-1 < t \leq 1$ with equality at 1, because the exponent $\frac{-1}{2} > -1$.

To finish your problem, simply let $t = \frac{x^2}{4}$. You should find that the interval of convergence becomes $-2 \leq x \leq 2$ (noting that $\frac{x^2}{4} \geq 0$ so that the interval of converges is actually $0 \leq \frac{x^2}{4} \leq 1$).